# How to use dual speakers in macOS

Tags: macos, audio, speakers

I am using macOS Catalina; there are 2 LG UltraFine displays with speakers in them. I can use one or the other fine, but it would be nice if I could use both speakers at the same time.

I tried making an aggregated device with the Audio MIDI Setup app as per the instruction of this [Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000).

[image: Created an aggregated device with both monitor speakers using Audio MIDI Setup]

Whenever I try to change the volume, macOS says that I can't (it shows the volume HUD with a no sign).

[image: Volume HUD saying I cannot change the volume]

Is it possible to have the volume play out of both monitor speakers? If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a 'Multi-Output Device' instead of 'Aggregate'.

You cannot control the volume with system control anyway. You could adjust volume in 'Audio MIDI Setup'.

Comment: So basically you can’t use multiple speakers in this case AND use the system volume?